# How to increment quantity column if record exists, else insert record?

Tags: sqlite

I've got the below sqlite database:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
    `idx`   INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    `qty`   INTEGER,
    `brand` TEXT,
    `type`  TEXT
);

insert into test (qty, brand, type) values (1, "Merc", "petrol");
insert into test (qty, brand, type) values (1, "Toyota", "diesel");
```

I want to insert another record but if it exists then I want to increase the qty field, so:

```
insert into test (qty, brand, type) values (1, "Merc", "diesel");
```

so would just increase the qty field by one, and

```
insert into test (qty, brand, type) values (1, "Merc", "petrol");
```

would insert a new record.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQLite is an embedded database, i.e., it is designed to be used together with an application.
The easiest way is to put the logic into the application:

```py
db.execute("UPDATE test SET qty = qty + 1 WHERE brand = ? AND type = ?",
           ["Merc", "diesel"])
if db.rows_affected == 0:
    db.execute("INSERT ...")
```

Comment: Thanks - excellent idea. I'm using it in Android so can easily do that.  :)

Answer (score 3):

As of version 3.24.0, SQLite supports [`UPSERT`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_UPSERT.html).

```sql
CREATE TABLE `test` (
    `idx`   INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    `qty`   INTEGER DEFAULT 1,
    `brand` TEXT,
    `type`  TEXT
    )
    UNIQUE (brand, type)
;


INSERT INTO test (qty, brand, type) VALUES ("Merc", "diesel")
    ON CONFLICT(brand, type) DO UPDATE SET qty = qty + 1;
INSERT INTO test (qty, brand, type) VALUES ("Merc", "diesel")
    ON CONFLICT(brand, type) DO UPDATE SET qty = qty + 1;
SELECT qty, brand, type FROM test;
```

Output:

> 2 Merc diesel